# Convert GeoJSON labels MBR to MapInfo text object

Tags: python, mapinfo, labeling

I'm using Dymo (https://github.com/migurski/Dymo/) to generate automatic point labels placement. The output of Dymo is GeoJSON containing MBRs of the positioned labels with the names of the labels in the attributes table. I would like to convert the GeoJSON table to a MapInfo text object table to finish the placement manually in MapInfo.

I can't find any info about that question.

Edit: Sample of Dymo output in JSON:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection", 
  "features": [
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon", 
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -74.033500000000004, 
          45.677299999999995
        ], 
        [
          -74.028294368743914, 
          45.677299999999995
        ], 
        [
          -74.028294368743914, 
          45.677506895418496
        ], 
        [
          -74.033500000000004, 
          45.677506895418496
        ], 
        [
          -74.033500000000004, 
          45.677299999999995
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }, 
  "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": {
    "preferred_placement": "", 
    "overlaps": 0, 
    "font_size": 6, 
    "name": "Label Name", 
    "font_file": "Fonts/arialbd.ttf", 
    "point_size": 0, 
    "justified": "left"
  }
}, 
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon", 
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -74.030500000000004, 
          45.768493442022979
        ], 
        [
          -74.025878017425526, 
          45.768493442022979
        ], 
        [
          -74.025878017425526, 
          45.768700000000003
        ], 
        [
          -74.030500000000004, 
          45.768700000000003
        ], 
        [
          -74.030500000000004, 
          45.768493442022979
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Are you able to post some sample output from Dymo?

Comment: Yes, I put the sample in the question.

Comment: Actually, I can do the conversion with FME, but any other solution would be appreciated.